# Add dd.hh:mm:ss.nnnnn time format to Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value in `dd.hh:mm:ss.nnnnn` format. Some of the examples are `32.11:45:40.93877`, `11:45:30.32012` which are in string format.

I want to add a perform addition of datetime value and above time span which is in string format. The value `30.12:43:10.98222` can be represented as 30 days 12 hours 43 minutes 10 seconds and 98222 milliseconds.

I wrote the following code (function) to get the result:

Pseudo code:

```
split the string split(5.11:45:40.90399, ':') and add into #temptable(id, value).

while(0 < @counter)
    select @val = value from #tempTable where id = @counter

    if (@counter = 0)
       split '5.11' in 5 and 11 by using charindex, substring, left, Convert to Int function. Also handle availability of day value
       datetimevalue = dateadd(day,5,datetimevalue)
       datetimevalue = dateadd(hour, 11, datetimevalue)

       if (@counter = 1)
           datetimevalue = dateadd(minute, 45, datetimevalue)
       if (@@counter = 2)
           split 40.90399 into 40 and 90399

       datetimevalue = dateadd(second, 40, datetimevalue)
       datetimevalue = dateadd(millisecond, 90399, datetimevalue)
End of while loop

return datetimevalue
```

Can we have an alternative solution or some change simplify the above process?

For now I was thinking of converting `hh:mm:ss` part to seconds and adding it as seconds thus reducing call of dateadd function.

Comment: well thats not a date. Its a time span. for eg: 5 days 11 hours 45 minutes and 40 seconds.I am not sure how to add timespan to datetime value

Comment: OK I should have seen that by looking more closely at the string, but it might be good to specify that in your question.

Comment: This isn't too bad once you have a decent string splitter. I would use this one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ The main reason is because this splitter is not only super fast it also returns the row number in the results and in your case this is critical to making it work. I would think a table valued function would make this pretty easy to work with. You should be able to do this in a single select statement with nested DATEADD calls pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to get that precision you can't use `DateTime`, you must use `DateTime2`.

Second, As Mayur Patil rightfully commented - the value you want to add is a time span, not a datetime value. There is no time span data type in Sql server, However, you can translate the string value into a time span using some string manipulations.

I came up with a suggested solution, 
However, there is a problem with this solution that I couldn't solve: Your milliseconds part might be bigger then 1000 (and in fact it is), so the results seems to be a little off. I've tried treating it as nanoseconds, but that didn't give the results I was expecting. Perhaps someone else might refine it or come up with a better way to do it:

First, separate the days from the time,
Next, separate the time into it's components,
Then, use DateAdd to add it all to the original date:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime2 = GETDATE()

DECLARE @S as varchar(20) = '32.11:45:40.93877'

;WITH CTE1 As
(
    SELECT  LEFT(@S, CHARINDEX('.', @S)-1) As TheDay,
            REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@S, CHARINDEX('.', @S) + 1, LEN(@S) - CHARINDEX('.', @S)), ':', '.') As TheTime
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT  CAST(TheDay As int) As TheDays, 
        CAST(PARSENAME(TheTime, 4) As Int) As TheHours,
        CAST(PARSENAME(TheTime, 3) As Int) As TheMinutes,
        CAST(PARSENAME(TheTime, 2) As Int) As TheSeconds,
        CAST(PARSENAME(TheTime, 1) As Int) As TheNanoSeconds
FROM CTE1
)

SELECT  @Date As OriginalDate,
        @S As TimeSpan,
        DATEADD(DAY, TheDays, 
            DATEADD(HOUR, TheHours,
                DATEADD(MINUTE, TheMinutes,
                    DATEADD(SECOND, TheSeconds,
                        DATEADD(NANOSECOND, TheNanoSeconds, @Date)
                    )
                )
            )
        ) As Result
FROM CTE2
```

Results:

```
OriginalDate                TimeSpan             Result
--------------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------
2016-06-20 16:23:30.7470000 32.11:45:40.93877    2016-07-23 04:09:10.7470939
```